Peticion GET o POST con variables (usuario y clave) android studio
estoy iniciando en la programación android, y pues que mejor que iniciar con la pantalla de login o de inicio de sesion? pues crei empezar muy bien pero no he podido avanzar con lo siguiente.
actualmente desde el emulador puedo conectarme al servidor a una pagina que me retorna un json, envio el usuario y clave al php y este consulta la BD y retorna los datos que quiero en un json. hasta alli bien, el problema es que no logro que los datos que se envian hacia el php (usuario y clave) sean los que el usuario teclea y luego le da al boton iniciar.
anexo codigo
package com.example.prueba_ea1

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity

import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import com.example.prueba_ea1.model.remote_resoult
import com.example.prueba_ea1.ui.theme.Prueba_EA1Theme
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.create
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Path
import retrofit2.http.Query

interface RetrofitService{
//funcion para realizar la consulta al servidor
    @GET("mobile_app/get_sesion_ini.php?login=rcampos&password=1234")
    suspend fun obt_user():remote_resoult //clase que contiene la estructura del json

}
       object RetrofitServiceFactory{ //objeto que hace las llamadas para la conexion al server
           fun makeRetrofitService(): RetrofitService{

               return Retrofit.Builder()
                   .baseUrl("https://servidor.org/")
                   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                   .build().create(RetrofitService::class.java)

           }



       }
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.login)//xml con los los editText usuario y clave y el boton de buscar
        val usuariov =findViewById<EditText>(R.id.usuario)
        val clavev =findViewById<EditText>(R.id.clave)
        val botonBuscarv = findViewById<Button>(R.id.boton_buscar)
           botonBuscarv.setOnClickListener {//evento onclick para que se inicie la consulta al server
            val mensaje = "Usuarios: ${usuariov.text}"
            Toast.makeText(this,mensaje,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()// mensjae de prueba que tengo la informacion que usuario coloco en el campo usuario

            val serviceweb = RetrofitServiceFactory.makeRetrofitService()
            lifecycleScope.launch {
            val resultado = serviceweb.obt_user()//funcion para obtener la respuesta del json despues de consultar el server
            val loobt = "Desde el server, Nombre:${resultado.nombre} cédula:${resultado.cedula} usuario:${resultado.usuario} "
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,loobt,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() //muestro la informacion que me devuelve el json
            }

        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    Prueba_EA1Theme {
        Greeting("Mundo Rolando")

    }
}


los comentarios fue lo que mas o menos fui entendiendo que era cada cosa.
mi entencion final es lograr pasarla al URL las 2 variables que recibo del usuario que serian:
usuariov y clavev y lograr algo como esto:
@GET("mobile_app/get_sesion_ini.php?login=usuariov&password=clavev")
